# How to reduce the maximum number of suggestions in Chosen Javascript Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete, jquery-chosen

By default, Chosen with jquery shows about 9 results in the dropdown autocomplete by default. I'd like to reduce this number to 4 results..

How do I do that?

Heres a link to the chosen project..

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out after some exploration...

change this CSS in chosen.css:

```
.chzn-container .chzn-results {
  max-height: 100px; #100px used to be 240px...
}
```